# How do you reject a message in WCF?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I'm moving to Azure which uses a security token to authenticate a user.  So now I'm passing the security token in the header of the message and reading it using an **IDispatchMessageInspector** behavior on the server side.  The basics mechanics work pretty well, but when the token can't be authenticated I need to reject it just as if it had failed the **UserNamePasswordValidator**.  Any ideas how I finish this code:

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
    if (!this.IsAuthenticated(securityToken))
    {
        <Return Error Message Structure>
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this SOAP or REST based?

Comment: No Soap, peanuts.  I'll take an answer for either.

Comment: For a RESTful service the obvious thing to do would be to return a server 403 response, with an optional response body stating what the information is.

Comment: Have you tried throwing an exception inside the if block?

Answer (score 3):

Simple option is to throw a [FaultException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576199(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
object IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
    try
    {
        if (!this.IsAuthenticated(securityToken))
        {
           throw new FaultException<string>("some message");
        }
    }      
    catch (FaultException e)
    {
        throw new FaultException<string>(e.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```

If you want something more elegant and control over the HttpStatus code that is returned (default is 500) then you can implement a Endpoint Behavior Extension which registers a Dispatch Message Inspector that watches for faults. See following post:

http://www.shulerent.com/2016/05/31/returning-custom-http-status-codes-for-wcf-soap-exceptions/